# IntersectionObserver generating more events than expected

Tags: javascript, browser

I'm not sure if this is expected/have understood it wrong

Let's say I have the following observer

```
new IntersectionObserver(console.log, {threshold: 1})
```

which is observing every element inside a `div`

^ I expect the `console.log` to only print those observed elements that disappear

But it also gets triggered for elements that have entered the viewport upon scrolling. Why is that? Isn't the meaning of threshold 1 to only notify me on element going out of the viewport?

This way I always have to iterate through the entries in the callback to figure out which elements are now not visible using the `isIntersecting` flag

Comment: _"When the callback is invoked, it receives a list of IntersectionObserverEntry objects, one for each observed target which has had the degree to which it intersects the root change such that the amount exposed crosses over one of the thresholds, **in either direction**."_

Comment: That said, can you please add a [mcve] that shows the actual problem because _"also gets triggered for elements that have entered the viewport"_ should not be the case with a threshold of `1`

Comment: should've read the document better!!

Comment: Unrelated: Java has that concept of dynamic proxies ... but that works with reflection. It is pretty powerful, but also a really advanced subject ... see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/reflection/proxy.html for example